# how can i loop through a grid to pick up specific rows in asp?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview in an asp web form and I want to loop through it in order to pick up only when the gender column is M and feed that row into a table?
My gridview code is bellow, thanks for any help.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="CourseCode,ClientNumber" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Height="237px" Width="801px">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CourseCode" HeaderText="CourseCode" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="CourseCode" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ClientNumber" HeaderText="ClientNumber" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ClientNumber" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="Date" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="Title" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Surname" HeaderText="Surname" SortExpression="Surname" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Forename" HeaderText="Forename" SortExpression="Forename" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Gender" HeaderText="Gender" SortExpression="Gender" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: i think you should adjust your data source.

Comment: Why don't you just get that information straight from the datasource? Why do you need to bind first then look through the gridview items??

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Gridview's

```
 protected void RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
```

event

And inside that event use something like this

```
if( DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Gender").ToString=="M")
   {
   //  do something
   }
```